# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type with blob type

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I'm trying to use sqlite as a database to save some things for my bot. Users are able to make characters and store a list of quests on that character. The character object is a collection of strings and a list, the names being that of the character itself and the user that created it, and the list being a list of quests. I am trying to store these character objects into the database.

here is how I am setting up my database:

```
import discord
import pso2 #pso2 is my own file with a bunch of objects relevant to the program
import sqlite3

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    db = sqlite3.connect('Fina.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS character_list
                (character_list BLOB)
            ''')

@bot.command(name='addChar', help='!addChar, makes a new character')
async def char(ctx, name):

    myChar = pso2.Character(ctx.author.name, name)
    character_list.append(myChar)

    db = sqlite3.connect('Fina.sqlite')#insert into database
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO character_list VALUES (?)', (myChar,))
    db.commit()
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Edmund\.virtualenvs\DiscordTestBot-uXrzxTSE\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Fina.py", line 75, in char
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO character_list VALUES (?)', (myChar,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

how pso2.Character() is set up:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, user, name):
        self.user = user
        self.name = name
        self.quest_list = Quest_list()

class Quest_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.quests = []
```

Comment: What does ```pso2.Character()``` return? ```BLOB``` is looking for ```bytes```.[Sqlite3/Python types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite-and-python-types)

Comment: It seems `myChar` is not `str` type.

Comment: (myChar,) makes it a tuple, pass in just myChar

Comment: pso2.Character() returns a character object. I'm not sure if it is stored as bytes or not and i'm not sure how to check.